# Access listbox from another class?

Tags: c#

I made a class so when the user selects item from listbox it uninstalls that item, except the problem is I can't access the list box. I tried public aswell, but in the code of form1.cs  the only thing clostest to that list box is

keep in mind name of listbox is ProgramslistBox
Ok guys I re edited this post;

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(ProgramsListbox.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select an item to uninstall!");
        }
        else
        {
            ProgramsListbox_SelectedIndexChanged("",EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

this code is the FORM1.CS class, and I have another class called UninstallItem.cs is where I want my code to be, this below is my other class

namespace PC_TECH_Registery_Cleaner
{
class UninstallItem
{

```
    public void uninstallSelectedItem()
    {
        Form1 c = new Form1();
        
    }
}
```

}

And this below is still in my FORM1.CS class, I was experimenting with it :

```
 public void ProgramsListbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //this will access the Uninstall item class so we can uninstall selected item.
        UninstallItem c = new UninstallItem();
        c.uninstallSelectedItem();
    }
```

Comment: Why not just call the method of your class from inside that event handler on the form?

Comment: Create a new constructor in your second form that takes a `Form` as parameter. Then pass the instance of the first form to the other form's constructor and store it in a property. Then you can access all controls of the first form from the second form via this property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your Form1.cs create instance of UnIstallItem class and use it. Then on Button Click call "RemoveSelected" method of UnInstaItem class by passing programsListBox to it and it should remove the selected item.

```
public class Form1:Form
{
    ListBox ProgramsListbox;
    UninstallItem unistall;

    public Form1(){
       InitializeComponent();
       uninstall = new UninstallItem();
       button1.Click+= button1_Click;
    }

    void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        unistall.RemoveSelected(ProgramsListbox);
    }
}
```

Then in your external class;

```
public class UninstallItem{
   public UninstallItem{}

   public void RemoveSelected(ListBox list)
    {
        if(list.SelectedIndex==-1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select Item from List");
            return;
        }
        list.Items.RemoveAt(list.SelectedIndex);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man sorry for late response forgot bout this post but the listContainer doesn't exist? EDIT, found it the listContainer is just name of class xD the main one.

Comment: I got error now list.SelectedIndex += uninstallSelectedItem; that line i put in my method, this is the uninstall class btw not the form1.cs

Comment: Done. Thanks for the extra help btw :)

Comment: I don't see what you changed though?

Comment: Becoz you did not send mr the code did you? And you said it worked. Anyway you know better

Comment: I edited my first post ... I never said it worked what the hell are you on about lol.

Comment: I changed answer based on your code. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Almost there man except on this line:     unistall.RemoveSelected(ProgramsListbox); the uninstall does not exist. NEVERMIND I found the problem. Though one thing when i press uninstall button message pops up twice that no item selected.

Comment: Hey man just quickly I figured it out thanks so much for help parameters are really useful! I just had to remove something from the code you gave me thanks again. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 easy ways to think about this are either

1. Call the method in your class from the event handler in your form
2. Have a method on your class which matches the signature of an event handler, and subscribe to the event.

---

The first requires no major change

```
private MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
public void ProgramsListbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myClass.DoSomething();
}
```

The second requires your class to have a specific method that matches the signature of that event handler currently in your form

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void DoSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var listBox = (ListBox)sender;
        // read selected index perhaps, or selected item maybe
    }
}
```

And then in your form

```
private MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    this.ProgramsListBox.SelectedIndexChanged += myClass.DoSomething;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I forgot that you putting code in the ProgramsListBox_SelectedIndeChanged it will do anything once you click on it. So I will just make code in my other class which will uninstall item from listbox?